# Customizg loss function in Word2vec

Tags: keras, nlp, gensim, word2vec, word-embedding

I have list of co-occurences and I want to train word2vec model with my own customized loss_function.

What is the best way to approach this?

1. Is it possible to set gensim Word2Vec model with my own function?
2. If not, is there an example to an implementation with keras?
3. If not, must I define everything totally from scratch?

Thanks!